# Using language files combined with PHP variables set on the page

Tags: php

I'm using language files to allow users to switch between English and Dutch.

The language files contain site text in arrays named `$lang`. The language is chosen using a GET method by clicking language links on top of the page. All of that works fine.

If I have `$lang['my_account']="My Account";` in the English language file, then adding `echo $lang['my_account'];` to the page correctly displays "My Account".

But I have a lot of titles which include PHP variables which are set on the page itself, for instance:

```
Account Statement on <?php echo $today; ?> for user <?php echo $user; ?>
```

Now I need to add multiple language support for those, and I'm stuck, because I can't have the $today and $user variables declared before I include the language file. So, my question is, do I have to add separate entries to the language files for "Account Statement on" and "for user" and do something like this on the page:

```
<?php echo $lang['acc_statement'].$today.$lang['for_user'].$user; ?>
```

Or is there a way around this?

Comment: Your suggestion is the first thing that would cross my mind as well, to be honest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but shouldn't something like [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) solve this problem:

```
$lang['account'] = "Account Statement on %s for user %s";
```

and then echo like:

```
echo sprintf($lang['account'], $today, $user);
```

Comment: That is also the accepted way of doing this, because other languages may need to change the word order. Never translate something that is less than a sentence.